# Infer column type SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Suppose I am using SQLAlchemy to upload a generic .csv file to an mssql server.

How can I infer the type of each column? It seems that one has to declare a column explicitly eg {'myvar' : Column(Integer)}. Is there a way for SQLAlchemy, or some other library, to infer the datatype of each column by itself?

VB has the function "TransferText" which can do just that , but I want to do this in python.

Comment: If you have a class `YourClass` then you can check `YourClass.your_attribute.type.python_type`

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work in my case. A generic .csv file contains no type or class information - only comma seperated strings. I can read the header to get the number and name of columns, and make a class where each parameter by default has type None, or String - but I can't infer if a string might represent another data type.

Comment: What are you uploading it *into*? That is, can you get the type information from the destination table?

Comment: I may need to create the table; otherwise one could just use the existing table parameters.

Comment: You'll have to write the inference algorithm yourself, e.g. read in each row and decide, for each column, if all the cells contain only numbers. There's no silver bullet inference algorithm because CSVs are not universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your data you may be able to get away with simply using `ast.literal_eval`.

```
import ast

assert isinstance(ast.literal_eval('1'), int)
assert isinstance(ast.literal_eval('1.0', float)
assert isinstance(ast.literal_eval('True', bool)
assert isinstance(ast.literal_eval('"foobar"', basestring)
```

You could also use something a bit more complex such as [messytables](https://github.com/okfn/messytables) which provides a `type_guess` method.

http://messytables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/